# Intentando modificar una tupla... list (T)[0] = 'item' ¿Dónde se guarda esto?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Intento aprender Python 2.7 y al llegar al tema de las tuplas y su inmutabilidad me he puesto hacer pruebas para ver si lo entendía. el caso,  se que para cambiar un item de una tupla antes debo convertirla a lista, e intentado hacer esto de otra manera:

```
>>> T = ('uno', 2, 3.0)
>>> list (T)[0] = 'item'
>>> T
('uno', 2, 3.0)
```

¿Por qué no cambia `T` y si algo ha cambiado (por que no he recibido ningún error) donde puedo ver ese cambio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien dices las tuplas son inmutables, `list(T)` no modifica nunca el contenido de `T`, simplemente crea una lista a partir de `T` y **la retorna**. `list (T)[0] = 'item'` primero crea una lista usando **`T`** que será almacenada en memoria y luego modifica el elemento con índice 0 (en este orden), pero como **no hay ninguna variable que tome la referencia del objeto retornado** este será destruido sin más por el GC (recolector de basura).

Debes si o si primero asignar una variable al retorno de `list` y luego modificar la lista usando esa variable para hacer referencia a ella:

```
>>> T = ('uno', 2, 3.0)
>>> T = list(T)
>>> T[0] = "item"
>>> T = tuple(T)
>>> ('item', 2, 3)
```

También puedes usar slicing y concatenado (aunque si se quiere una tupla que se pueda modificar mejor usar una lista desde el principio y hacer casting a tuple si es necesario, para hacer el objeto "hashable" por ejemplo):

```
>>> T = ('uno', 2, 3.0)
>>> T = ("item",) + T[1:]
>>> T
('item', 2, 3.0)
```

Para ser estrictos al hacer `>>> list(T)`, el recolector de basura de cPython no destruye el objeto inmediatamente  en el caso de estar usando un intérprete interactivo como en este caso. La razón se debe al funcionamiento  del prompt del propio intérprete interactivo, que almacena el retorno de la función de forma automática en una variable `_` (lo que permite entre otras cosas que aparezca la salida impresa). Mientras esta referencia exista el GC no va a destruir el objeto.

Podemos ver este comportamiento creando una pequeña clase con un metodo `__del__` customizado:

```
>>> class MiClase:
        def __del__(self):
            print("Objeto {} destruido.".format(self))


>>> MyClase()
<__main__.MiClase object at 0x00000243454C2B00>
>>> 5
Objeto <__main__.MiClase object at 0x00000243454C2B00> destruido.
5
```

El objeto solo se destruye cuando se llama a otra función o método ya que es en ese momento en el que la variable `_` se reasigna al nuevo retorno, el GC detecta que el anterior objeto carece de referencias y lo destruye. Como se puede ver en el ejemplo, al ingresar `>>> 5` la variable interna que apuntaba a la instancia de `MiClase` pasa a hacer referencia al entero por lo que la instancia de `MiClase` queda sin referencias a merced del GC que la manda a mejor vida.

Esto no pasa si no se usa un intérprete interactivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que intentas hacer, la linea 2 debe ser:

```
T=list (T)[0] = 'item'
```

para reasignar la conversión de la tupla en lista a T.

Si no, lo que
estas haciendo es convertirla, pero como no la estás asignando a nada
no puedes volver a acceder a ella (y T sigue siendo tu tupla inicial).

Aquí tienes el ejemplo:

```
>>> T = ('uno', 2, 3.0)
>>> T=list (T)[0] = 'item'
>>> T
'item'
```